# Calculation issue in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, math

So i am just doing a simple calculation in my app but somehow I'm not getting expected answer with the formula.

```
var i = 90 / 60 * 1000
```

This always returns 1000 instead of 1500

It seems some issue with the floating point from `90 / 60` operation, but I'm not sure how to handle it in Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

The whole number (integer) division `90 / 60` results in `1`, namely the places in front of the decimal point. Better divide by a floating point number:

```
var i = 90 / 60f * 1000
// result: 1500.0
```

Comment: What if i declare i as Double, it still results in 1000. Am i missing any basic concept after 4 years of coding or what! 